# will my data collide?

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services, http-post

I post data to remote php file and there using post method am saving data to remote mysql database as simple as it is.

But my worry is am getting data every 30sec to 1minute and sending to server via http post from android mobile i.e from 'N' no of mobiles so, will data collide? is there a chance of loosing data? ex: from 100mobiles

currently am using 000webhost.com free hosting, am planning to move for paid one.

But do I need to buffer all incoming data and then save will it avoid data loss? or continue with my same approach and have high speed server?

I dont have much knowledge about maximum at what speed server can process incoming data. what if many data comes from many mobiles at same time? do I need to manually buffer or server does for me.

if manual buffer please share some code so that I can understand better. 
(battery of android mobile I have taken care and am using gps and network provider)

```
<?php

$longitude = $_POST['lon'];
$latitude= $_POST['lat'];
$imei= $_POST['imei'];
$speed = $_POST['sp'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
if($longitude != "" && $latitude != "")
{
$mysql_host = "xxx";
$mysql_database = "xxx";
$mysql_user = "xxx";
$mysql_password = "xxx";

$con=mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password ) OR DIE ("Unable to select db".mysql_error());

if($con)
{

    mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

        //check if imei number already exists

        $sql="select emp_name from mob_reg where imei='$imei'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        if((mysql_num_rows($result))== 0)
        {
            echo "invalid";

        }
         else
        {
     $sql="insert into details(imei,lon,lat,speed,date) values('$imei','$longitude','$latitude','$speed','$date');";
     mysql_query($sql) or die("couldnt insert");
        }


}
else{
    echo 'invalid';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You always need to buffer, even if your site is not down, the network may be. Also, when you do upgrades, it's nice not to have to count the seconds the upgrade takes not to lose data.

Comment: are you speaking about network in mobile? if yes then am storing it in database if internet is not available and then sending once net is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about buffering in your code.
Your code should deal with each request as efficiently as possible.

Your infrastructure should be set up according to how much traffic you expect.

If your service is going to be very busy, then you can think about load-balancing (having more than one web-server and/or database server handle the incoming requests, depending on where the bottlenecks are)